# Split or extract a Value from a vector SCALA

Tags: scala, dictionary, vector

I am working with the following list in a text file:

```
10,44,22
10,47,12
15,38,3
15,41,30
16,44,15
16,47,18
22,38,21
22,41,42
34,44,40
34,47,36
40,38,39
40,41,42
45,38,27
45,41,30
46,44,45
46,47,48
```

I am creating some indexes to analysis the table, then if each column is (s,p,o) and I create a map that is P -> SO I create it of the form

```
val dicP_SO: scala.collection.mutable.Map[Int, Vector[Vector[Int]]] = collection.mutable.Map[Int, Vector[Vector[Int]]]()
```

I read the file, and create the mapping with

```
if (dicP_SO.contains(p)) {
   P_SO = dicP_SO.apply(p) :+ Vector(s, o) //To add to the same key the diff
   dicP_SO += (p -> P_SO)                  //(s,o)
}else dicP_SO += (p -> Vector(Vector(s,o)))
```

in this way if I put as key the 38, and I run the following code:

```
dicP_SO.getOrElse(38,Vector(0))
```

I get the following:

```
Vector(Vector(15, 3), Vector(22, 21), Vector(40, 39), Vector(45, 27))
```

My quetion is the following: I need each vector[Int] that are inside, I try to declare a variable

```
val a:Vector[Int] = dicP_SO.getOrElse(yi,Vector(0))
```

I am getting the error that a Vector[Any] does not conform to Vector[Int] and I don't know why is this error and how fix it

Comment: Instead of using `Map[Int, Vector[Vector[Int]]]` for `dicP_SO`, you should probably use `Map[Int, Vector[Int]]`. You don't seem to need the `Vector[Vector[Int]]` type at all.

Comment: it is because I need to save the corresponding pairs of int, (15,3), (22,21)...etc

Comment: If you want to preserve a pair of `Int`, you should use this instead: `Map[Int, Vector[(Int, Int)]]`. Using `Vector[Vector[Int]]` would allow you to put values such as `Vector(0)`, or `Vector(1, 2, 3)`, which are not a pair of `Int`.

Comment: It is no way to create a loop or something to pass troght this vector like for(...) { val a:Vector[Int] = dicP_SO.getOrElse(yi,Vector(0)).get(0)....} ?

Comment: See my updated answer for how you can loop through a value taken from the `Map`

Answer (score 0):

Since `dicP_SO.getOrElse(38,Vector(0))` return type is: `Vector[Any]`, when you assign it to `Vector[Int]`, the compiler throw this **error**.

You can do it by:

```
dicP_SO.get(38).map(_.flatten).getOrElse(Vector(0)) //flatten nest Vector[Vector[Int]] to Vector[Int], and `getOrElse`
```

use `flatten` to flat a **nest collection**:

```
Vector(Vector(1)).flatten
> Vector(1)
```

Comment: But I can not lose the pairs information, with flatten, I am getting just one Vector(21, 9, 28, 27, 39, 3, 45, 33) and not the pairs Vector(21 ,9) Vector (28,27) etc.....

Comment: If you need the pairing information, you'll need to return a `Vector[Vector[Int]]`, .e.g `val a: Vector[Vector[Int]] = dicP_SO.getOrElse(yi, Vector(Vector(0)))`

Answer (score 0):

You should already have output as you want, you just need a correct way to access them

```
scala> val rdd = dicP_SO.getOrElse(38, Vector(0))
rdd: scala.collection.immutable.Vector[Any] = Vector(Vector(15, 3), Vector(22, 21), Vector(40, 39), Vector(45, 27))

scala> rdd.foreach(println)
Vector(15, 3)
Vector(22, 21)
Vector(40, 39)
Vector(45, 27)
```

**Edited**

If you want to access each vector and assign to a variable you can do

```
scala> val v1 = rdd(0)
v1: Any = Vector(15, 3)

scala> println(v1)
Vector(15, 3)
```

Comment: but you just are printing the output, if I want to store each one in a variable?

Answer (score 0):

The reason you have compile error is that the value in the map is in the type of `Vector[Vector[Int]]`. So when you do `getOrElse(yi, Vector(0))`, the `Vector(0)` value will have type `Vector[Int]`, and hence the compiler will try to refer the returned type of the two types ( `Vector[Vector[Int]]` and `Vector[Int]`) as `Vector[Any]`.

Given the data that you have, I'd recommend using these data structure and code:

```
val dicP_SO: mutable.Map[Int, List[(Int, Int)]] = mutable.Map[Int, List[(Int, Int)]]()
```

Then for inserting new info:

```
val currentValues = if (dicP_SO.contains(p)) {
    dicP_SO.remove(p)
} else {
    List.empty[(Int, Int)]
}

dicP_SO += p -> currentValues :+ (s, o)
```

To retrieve info for a key `yi`:

```
val a: List[(Int, Int)] = dicP_SO.getOrElse(yi, List.empty[(Int, Int)] // return empty list if the key doesn't exists
```

Then you can process the information however you want, e.g.:

```
a.map { case (s, o) => /* do something with s and o */ }
```

Comment: Why are you removing the element of the key(p), if you see, the element p = 38 has 4 vectors... the reason of the if is to store this 4 elements,

Comment: I remove it, then add it later (the line outside of the `if/else`), so the key will still be there, with the new list of values. It's basically equivalent to your `apply(p)` then `+=` operation, but in this case I use `remove(p)` then `+=`.